# Rendering data in php from three different tables using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am having three tables.

base_income_tble:

```
id      base_income
------------------------
 1        Grants from government
 2        other grants
 3        Taxes
```

sub_income_tble:

```
 id      base_id      sub_income
 ---------------------------------------
 1         1          Special Grants
 2         1          General Grants
 3         2          Local authorities
 4         2          private
 5         3          Professional tax
 6         3          garbage tax
 7         3          light tax
```

inner_subincome_tble:

```
id    sub_id      inner_subincome
-------------------------------------
 1       1        matching grant
 2       1        XIIIth finance commission
 3       1        GIA members salary Grant
 4       2        Grants
 5       2        Grants in Lieu
```

I want to get the values from three tables regarding the id's related with each table.

I tried the below query:

```
select base_income, sub_income,inner_subincome from base_income_tble left join 
sub_income_tble ON base_income_tble.id = sub_income_tble.base_id left join 
inner_subincome_tble 
on sub_income_tble.id = inner_subincome_tble.sub_id OR sub_income_tble.id = 
inner_subincome_tble.sub_id;
```

And getting values:

[image]

I want to display the data as below format in html:

```
Grants from Government
     special Grants
        Matching grant
        XIIIth finance commission 
        GIA members salary Grant
     General Grants
        Grants
        Grants in Lieu 
other grants
     Local authorities
     private
```

It is possible to use nested foreach to render the data as above format, if possible what are the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

First method that comes to mind -

1) Get a list of all the data from the database, including the `id` numbers

```
select b.id as base_id, s.id as sub_id, i.id as inner_id, b.base_income, s.sub_income, i.inner_subincome from base_income_tble b left join sub_income_tble s on b.id = s.base_id left join inner_subincome_tble i on s.id = i.sub_id

+---------+--------+----------+------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+
| base_id | sub_id | inner_id | base_income            | sub_income        | inner_subincome          |
+---------+--------+----------+------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+
|       1 |      1 |        1 | Grants from government | Special Grants    | Matching grant           |
|       1 |      1 |        2 | Grants from government | Special Grants    | XIIIth finance comission |
|       1 |      1 |        3 | Grants from government | Special Grants    | GIA members              |
|       1 |      2 |        4 | Grants from government | General Grants    | Grants                   |
|       1 |      2 |        5 | Grants from government | General Grants    | Grants in Lieu           |
|       2 |      3 |     NULL | Other grants           | Local authorities | NULL                     |
|       2 |      4 |     NULL | Other grants           | Private           | NULL                     |
|       3 |      5 |     NULL | Taxes                  | Professional tax  | NULL                     |
|       3 |      6 |     NULL | Taxes                  | Garbage tax       | NULL                     |
|       3 |      7 |     NULL | Taxes                  | Light tax         | NULL                     |
+---------+--------+----------+------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+
```

2) Build that into a recursive array

```
$data = array();

while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows)){

    $bId = 'id' . $r['base_id'];
    $sId = 'id' . $r['sub_id'];
    $iId = 'id' . $r['inner_id'];


    if( !array_key_exists($bId, $data) )
        $data[$bId] = array('title' => $r['base_income'], 'values' => array());

    if( $r['sub_id'] && !array_key_exists($sId, $data[$bId]['values']) )
        $data[$bId]['values'][$sId] = array('title' => $r['sub_income'], 'values' => array());

    if( $r['sub_id'] && $r['inner_id'] )
        $data[$bId]['values'][$sId]['values'][$iId] = array('title' => $r['inner_subincome']);
}
```

Contents of the `$data` array after this -

```
Array
(
    [id1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Grants from government
            [values] => Array
                (
                    [id1] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Special Grants
                            [values] => Array
                                (
                                    [id1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [title] => Matching grant
                                        )

                                    [id2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [title] => XIIIth finance comission
                                        )

                                    [id3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [title] => GIA members
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [id2] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => General Grants
                            [values] => Array
                                (
                                    [id4] => Array
                                        (
                                            [title] => Grants
                                        )

                                    [id5] => Array
                                        (
                                            [title] => Grants in Lieu
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [id2] => Array
        (
            [title] => Other grants
            [values] => Array
                (
                    [id3] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Local authorities
                            [values] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [id4] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Private
                            [values] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [id3] => Array
        (
            [title] => Taxes
            [values] => Array
                (
                    [id5] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Professional tax
                            [values] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [id6] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Garbage tax
                            [values] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [id7] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Light tax
                            [values] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

The `title` element stores the name of the income, and `values` stores the entries that should be displayed underneath that. You just need a recursive function now that takes an array, outputs the title and loops through the values, calling itself for each one. (You could probably also do this with nested foreach)

An alternative approach would be to store all the data in a single table. Just have `id`, `parent_id` and `income` fields, with the `parent_id` field being `NULL` for the top level entries, and the relevant `id` it should come under for everything else. The code to display this efficiently would be quite different to the above though.